# How to make ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer work on a universal app

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

My understanding is that an Exit element "flys out" of the page on transition and the Entrance elemnent "flys in". I am able to get the "fly in" transition to occur, but not the "fly out" from a listview:

Here's my list - when I click an item nothing happens. I am not even sure what elements to play with to try and get it to work - there's very little documentation:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2" ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.IsExitElement="True">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And here's my second page (which does "fly in"):

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="sdfsdfsdfsdf" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.IsEntranceElement="True" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped" IsTapEnabled="True"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I got same problem, no luck in finding docs :(

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and turns out the problem was in the transition declarations. So in your Page.Transitions where you define transitions add the following code

```
 <Page.Transitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <NavigationThemeTransition>
            <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                <CommonNavigationTransitionInfo IsStaggeringEnabled="True"/>
            </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
        </NavigationThemeTransition>
    </TransitionCollection>
</Page.Transitions>
```

So this is the page from where the list item is suppose to flyout. And notice that DefaultNavigation is CommonNavigationTransition type and **NOT** ContinnumNavigation type.

And in the page where list item flies in which is working for you the default navigation is of type ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo. And goes something like this

```
<Page.Transitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <NavigationThemeTransition>
            <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                <ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo/>
            </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
        </NavigationThemeTransition>
    </TransitionCollection>
</Page.Transitions>
```